# how does tf.while_loop() execute it body part in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

```py
import tensorflow as tf

n = tf.constant(3)
a = tf.constant(0)

def cond(a, n):
    return a < n

def body(a, n):
    print("box")
    return a+1, n

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    a, n = tf.while_loop(cond, body, [a, n])
    res = sess.run([a, n])
    print(res)
```

I expect the result to be

```
box
box
box
[10, 10]
```

However, the result was

```
box
[10, 10]
```

It seems the `body` function only executed once.
But if that is the case, then the result should be `[1, 10]`instead of `[10, 10]`.

I wonder why it appears like this and how while_loop execute its body part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It prints once when the graph is created. After the graph is created, during execution, there is no operation to print. If you want to print during execution phase you have to specify explicitly the operation to print. For example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

n = tf.constant(3)
a = tf.constant(0)

def cond(a, n):
    return a < n

def body(a, n):
    return tf.Print(a + 1, [], message='box'), n # <-- op for increment and print

a, n = tf.while_loop(cond, body, [a, n])

with tf.Session() as sess:

    res = sess.run([a, n])
    print(res)
# box
# box
# box
# [3, 3]
```

Note from [tf.Print()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Print) docs:

> Note: This op prints to the standard error. It is not currently compatible
>     with jupyter notebook (printing to the notebook *server's* output, not into
>     the notebook).